# LLVM bitcode library '.bc' and example of its usage in C++ project

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, bitcode

I want to use Apache TVM in WASM environment and for that I have compiled runtime library using LLVM like the tutorial suggests. As the outcome, I have a library with `.bc` format and a little surfing on the internet has shown that it is LLVM-specific format.

How can I use this `.bc` file in my C++ project? Obviously, I can not link it as my usual static/dynamic librares. Do I need to recompile it into static `.a` library, for instance?

Comment: Related: [How to make llvm .bc file executable?](/q/32523847/11107541)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [LLVM bitcode file](https://llvm.org/docs/BitCodeFormat.html). You can convert it into an object file by using [llc](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llc.html), like `llc -filetype=obj foo.bc`.

You can build the object file as part of an executable (`clang++ -o foo foo.o`)

Or you can turn the object file into a suitable binary type, such as a static library. Ex. `llvm-ar rcs libfoo.a foo.o`. Once you have the library binary, you can link to it how you normally would link to a library of that type. `clang++ -o foo -L/path/to/directory/containing/libfoo.a -lfoo`